# Proper way to do row correlations in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to calculate the correlation across two rows of a Pandas DataFrame. It is easy to calculate the correlation across two rows when all entries are of a numerical type, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
example_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 30), np.arange(10))
example_df.iloc[1, :].corr(example_df.iloc[2, :])
```

But if the DataFrame is of mixed type, you get an error when calculating the correlation even when you choose only the subset of numerical entries:

```
example_df['Letter'] = 'A'
example_df.iloc[1, :-1].corr(example_df.iloc[2, :-1])
```

*AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'sqrt'*

The Pearson's correlation function makes use of the square root function and that function doesn't exist for an object type so it can't do the correlation. You have to manually change the type to float and then you can calculate the correlation.

```
example_df.iloc[1, :-1].astype('float64').corr(example_df.iloc[2, :-1].astype('float64'))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these are any better than what you did, but here's a way with numpy:

```
np.corrcoef(df_example.iloc[1:3, :-1])

array([[ 1.        , -0.37194563],
       [-0.37194563,  1.        ]])
```

And here's a way with pandas:

```
df_example.iloc[1:3, :-1].T.corr()

          1         2
1  1.000000 -0.371946
2 -0.371946  1.000000
```

If you want to compare non-contiguous rows, adjust `iloc` like this:

```
df_example.iloc[[1, 4], :-1].T.corr()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the non-float column(s) in the index

```
example_df = example_df.set_index(['Letter'], append=True)
```

so that the rows are once again purely of float dtype. Then

```
example_df.iloc[1, :].corr(example_df.iloc[2, :])
```

works as before.